# 3D surface with constrained draw on it and transparency added

Tags: plotting

This is a nice draw

```
ContourPlot3D[{x y - z, 2 x + 3 y - 5}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 
  2}, ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Opacity[0.4]}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Red, Thickness[.01]}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]
```

which gives
[image]

Now I would like to change the color and add transparency to the front part of the 3D surface, and draw dashed lines to represent projections on the 3 axes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YB8aV.png)?

Comment: J.M. I am interested by the way you do this but in fact I would like to keep the frontal aspect of the surface. And by the way how to add the projections

Comment: OK, I don't understand what "frontal aspect of the surface" is supposed to mean, at all. I interpreted your "change the color and add transparency to the front part of the 3D surface" to mean that the front part of the saddle cut off by the plane would be transparent (that can be accomplished via `MeshShading`). As for projections, you want shadows of these two surfaces, or just the parabola formed by the intersection?

Comment: Sorry I must not be enough clear. I want the front part of the surface that is the one which is more or less inside the surface delimited by the axes x and y to be transparent to be able to see some dashed lines from the maximum to the axes